# How to use array_to_string in PostgreSQL to change column data type?

Tags: database, postgresql

I am trying to figure out how to use `array_to_string` in PostgreSQL to change a column's data type.
Currently my column has arrays, for example: `["7856", "2345"]`. Which I would like to change to a string: `7856, 2345`.

Currently I can just do this with SELECT but can't figure out how to alter the data. So far I have just been using:

`SELECT array_to_string(myColumnn,',') as myColumn from myTable`

Is there a way to use this to permanently change the data type in the column?

Thank you

Comment: Storing delimited values in a column is a bad design decision to begin with. But if you really want to de-normalize your data, then at least stick with proper arrays rather than the dreaded comma separated values.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
ALTER COLUMN myColumn TYPE VARCHAR 
USING array_to_string(myColumnn, ',');
```

[Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html)